# Is there a Talmudic source for this saying

Tags: talmud-gemara

I was asked if this saying, or a similar concept is found in the Talmud: "Not everything that one thinks, one should verbalize. Not everything that is said should be written. Not everything that is written should be published". Any source for this?

Comment: Any source? Or Talmudic specifically?

Comment: Sayings of Rabbi Menachem Mendel Kotzk : #26 - "Not every thought should be said. Not every speech should be written down. And not all writings are fit for print." [https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4287676/jewish/48-Wise-and-Deep-Sayings-of-Rabbi-Menachem-Mendel-of-Kotzk.htm]

Comment: I remember hearing a similar quote in the name of Maimonides.

Comment: הוו דלא לוסיף עלה

Comment: @kouty can you please translate your comment, and indicate where can I find it?

Comment: Why do people answer in the comments I see this done many times even when it’s a full answer like חידה wrote above.

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy Here the OP asked for Talmudic

Comment: @YehoshuaLevy people sometimes don't have time to write a full answer but want to be helpful and get their answer out. In a case like this, the question asked for a Talmudic source and the comment provides a more recent source. Still would make an excellent answer as it is likely there is no Talmudic source. Anyone is welcome to pick up anything in the comments and reuse them for an answer, see https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5231/11501 and https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4279/11501